# How should one go about proving a differential formula using Induction?

Tags: derivatives, induction, exponential-function

I have the following problem I need to solve, and while I am very familiar with Mathematical Induction I do not know how to approach this. Help would be very appreciated.

The Question is as follows:
The Function $f$ is defined by $f(x)=x e^{2x}$. Prove by the principle of Mathematical induction that for every integer $n>=1$

$$ f^{n} (x)=(2^nx + n2^{n-1})e^{2x}$$ where $f^{(n)}(x)$ represents the $n^{th}$ derivative of $f(x)$. By considering $f^{(n)}(x)$ for $n=1$ and $n=2$, show that there is one minimum point $P$ on the graph of $f$, and find the coordinates of $P$

Comment: Start with your base case, then assume there is some $k$ such that $f^k(x)$ is the $k$th derivative of that function. Then show that $f^{k+1}(x)$ has the desired form by taking the derivative of $f^k(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n=0$ it's true.

Let $f^{(n)}(x)=(2^nx + n2^{n-1})e^{2x}.$

Thus, $$f^{(n+1)}(x)=\left((2^nx + n2^{n-1})e^{2x}\right)'=2^n2^{2x}+(2^nx+n2^{n-1})2^{2x}\cdot2=\left(2^{n+1}x+(n+1)2^n\right)e^{2x}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The base case:
$$
f'(x)=e^{2x}+2xe^{2x}
$$
so that's good.

Now suppose 
$$
f^{(n-1)}(x)=(2^{n-1}x+(n-1)2^{n-2})e^{2x}
$$
then 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}f^{(n-1)}(x)=f^{(n)}(x)=(2^{n-1})e^{2x}+2(2^{n-1}x+(n-1)2^{n-2})e^{2x}\\
=2^{n-1}e^{2x}+(2^{n}x+(n-1)2^{n-1})e^{2x}\\
=(2^nx+n2^{n-1})e^{2x}
$$
as required.